# AVPLayer takes too long time to be recovered from buffering state

Tags: ios, streaming, avplayer

I have some problem developing streaming player for iOS. When playing the video in streaming mode, it sometimes changed to buffering state for many reasons. it is fine, but the problem is that it takes too long time to be recovered from buffering state. At that condition, It cannot resumed when I force to play. It cannot show any AVPlayerItemStatusFailed. If you have any idea or solution for this problem, please help me.

ps> English is not my first language. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: It's definitely not because of the connection speed?

Comment: NO, it's not . My player show the buffering state like other streaming player. so I already check the buffering state (and also check playbackBufferEmpty, playbackLikelyToKeepUp. and so on )

Comment: For example, It start buffering when 20% of total duration. It cannot be resumed until 50% is buffered.... for about 5 minutes total running time movie.